# Regex find groups and matches from a log file

Tags: python, regex

I have a log file with a lot of lines.
Example:

```
219.133.7.154 - price5585 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:53 -0700] "GET /incubate/incubate HTTP/1.1" 201 12126
```

I need as the output something like this:

```
{host: 219.133.7.154, user: price5585, date: 21/Jun/2019:15:45:53 -0700, req: GET /incubate/incubate HTTP/1.1}
```

I really struggle with that and got only 2 first things working.
Here is my code:

```
pattern = """
(?P<host>.*) #Host name
(-\ ) 
(?P<username>\w*)  #username

(?P<time>\w*) #Time

"""
```

How should pattern look, so I can extract everything I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can omit this part as a capture group `(-\ )` and while this part `(?P<host>.*)` works for the given example data, the `.*` can be non greedy preventing some backtracking as it will first match until the end of the string.

This group `(?P<time>\w*)` does not match anything, as the next text to match is  `[21/Jun/2019:15:45:53 -0700]` and `\w*` matches optional word characters.

---

You could write the pattern as:

```
(?P<host>.*?) - (?P<username>\w+) \[(?P<date>[^][]*)] "(?P<req>[^"]+)"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UkS3Z9/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/NDJnlv)

For example

```
import re

pattern = r"(?P<host>.*?) - (?P<username>\w+) \[(?P<date>[^][]*)] \"(?P<req>[^\"]+)\""
s = "219.133.7.154 - price5585 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:53 -0700] \"GET /incubate/incubate HTTP/1.1\" 201 12126"
m = re.match(pattern, s)

if m:
    print(m.groupdict())
```

Output

```
{'host': '219.133.7.154', 'username': 'price5585', 'date': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:53 -0700', 'req': 'GET /incubate/incubate HTTP/1.1'}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Is it also possible to filter out only "GET" requests? In my log file I have many others

Comment: @OlgaWold You could start the match of the last group with `GET ` see https://regex101.com/r/Xy8u6u/1

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use regex? Because your goal can be easily achieved by
parsing fields separated by whitespaces:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

LINE = "219.133.7.154 - price5585 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:53 -0700] \"GET /incubate/incubate HTTP/1.1\" 201 12126"

body = LINE.split("\"")[1]
split_line = LINE.split(" ")

output_dict = {"host": split_line[0],
               "user": split_line[2],
               "date": " ".join([split_line[3], split_line[4]]),
               "req": body}
print(output_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'host': '219.133.7.154', 'user': 'price5585', 'date': '[21/Jun/2019:15:45:53 -0700]', 'req': 'GET /incubate/incubate HTTP/1.1'}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the use of regex:

```
import re
line = '219.133.7.154 - price5585 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:53 -0700] "GET /incubate/incubate HTTP/1.1" 201 12126'
pat = r'(\S+) - (\S+) \[(.+)\] "(.+)"'
m = re.match(pat, line)
dic = {'host': m.group(1), 'user': m.group(2), \
    'date': m.group(3), 'req': m.group(4)}
print(dic)

{'host': '219.133.7.154', 'user': 'price5585', 'date': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:53 -0700', 'req': 'GET /incubate/incubate HTTP/1.1'}
```